# Looking for instructions for Air Canada Mega Bloks polybag 99911/99912

Tags: instructions, clone-brands

When I was a child I received a Mega Bloks airplane set on an Air Canada flight. I still have most of the pieces but cannot find the instructions.

The closest I can find is [this eBay image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlYNP.jpg) of 99913 but I'm looking for the other sets shown on the bag.

Anyone have an image of these set instructions?

Comment: Hello and welcome! That EBay image shows both 99911 and 99912 on the side in quite some detail. You should be able to figure out how to build those planes just from looking at those pictures, as these sets have very few pieces. Wouldnt that be enough?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a little hard for me to make out completely from that photo. I was hoping for something a little more clear

Answer (score 3):

https://www.ebay.ca/itm/Mega-Bloks-1997-Air-Canada-99911-New-Sealed-Fast-Shipping-/363045948319 has images, one of which is the back of the bag, which shows the instructions.

[image]

Comment: Nice find, RSchulz! Your worry about copyright infringement might be valid, but until it is cleared, I took the liberty to embed the image via Imgur, so that it doesn't get lost if Ebay decides to cease hosting it anymore. I have opened [a question on meta](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/527/3631) to discuss this, feel free to drop by either to chip in with your opinion or hear the others' views.

Comment: Thanks - but I can not comment there, as I do not have sufficient reputation. I find that site rule weird, that I can brashly answer a question, but not add a comment asking for clarification before I answer.