# Looking for instructions for Nanoblock Synthesizer (NBC_038)

Tags: instructions, 3rd-party

I was given a [Nanoblock Synthesizer](https://nanoblock.com.au/products/synthesizer) (NBC_038) at Christmas last year and frankly am feeling really guilty for not having built it and put it on the piano yet. Sadly, I've lost the instructions. I've searched a fair bit without success. Does anyone have the instructions or know where I can get them?

Comment: *(Due diligence: I checked to see if [Nanoblock was on topic](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/) and it seems so, and I checked to see if instructions requests are on-topic, and found a few (such as [this one](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/12888/)). The [on-topic help page](/help/on-topic) didn't mention instructions, nor did the [don't ask help page](/help/dont-ask), so I think it's okay. Apologies, though, if not. In particular I'm slightly worried about [copyright ramifications](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/527/).)*

Comment: This is a good and acceptable question, T.J. We typically handle LEGO questions, so finding an answer to a Nanoblocks question might take longer, also because unlike LEGO the other brands don’t have as much of a knowledge repository out on the Internet (company-provided or fan-provided).

Comment: Thanks @PhilB! I appreciate the confirmation, as you can tell I was only about 85% sure. :-)

Comment: Welcome T.J. and thanks for the due diligence, I wish every new user would be so thorough as you are :)

Comment: Thanks @zovits! But I don't deserve too much credit, I'm new here but I'm an 11-year veteran at StackOverflow, so I know a fair bit out off-topic questions. :-D Thanks to you and Phil B. and Alex for being such a welcoming community! It seems like I often have a different experience on other SE sites. You folks are great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Among other printed instructions for Nanoblock kits found on [Fandom Wiki](https://nanoblocks.fandom.com/wiki/NBC_Line) there is one for Synthesizer (NBC_038) kit as well:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I found [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-y6Ij5ELLZA) on YouTube for model speed build. Playing on 0.25 speed produce an acceptable result with parts being used in each step. At the second part of the video instruction sheet is also visible (image has been rotated, compared to video):

[image]

Comment: Great stuff, Alex!